# Event observer redirecting... notice message not showing in some cases

Tags: redirect, customer-session, messages

I have a module which redirects the customer to a specific page `trade/index/login` if they are on a certain store and not logged in, in certain cases.

**config.xml:**

```
    ...
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <controller_action_before>
                    <class>mymodule_tradecustomers/observer</class>
                    <method>redirectNotLoggedIn</method>
                </controller_action_before>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
    ...
```

**Observer.php:**

```
public function redirectNotLoggedIn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

    if ($storeId == 2 || Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
         return $this;  
    }

    $route = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName());
    $controller = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName());
    $requestedUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();

    /* Check 1 */
    if($route == 'catalog'){
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addNotice('You need a trade account to access the requested area of the website. Please apply or log in below.');
        $requestedUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($requestedUrl);
        $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('trade/index/login',array('referer' => $requestedUrl));
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
        return;
    }

    /* Check 2 */       
    if(strpos($requestedUrl,'download-the-catalogue') !== false){
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addNotice('You need a trade account to access the requested area of the website. Please apply or log in below.');
        $requestedUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($requestedUrl);
        $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('trade/index/login',array('referer' => $requestedUrl));
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
        return;
    }

    /* Check 3 */
    if($route == 'cms'){
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addNotice('You need a trade account to access the requested area of the website. Please apply or log in below.');
        $requestedUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($requestedUrl);
        $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('trade/index/login',array('referer' => $requestedUrl));
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
        return;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Check 1, Check 2 and Check 3 redirect to `trade/index/login` with the referer, is expected.

My issue is with the notice message.

If I go to the catalog pages (Check 1), the message 'You need a trade account to access the requested area of the website. Please apply or log in below.' is showing on `trade/index/login`.

However, if I go to the CMS page download-the-catalogue (Check 2), or if the route is cms (Check 3), I am redirected to `trade/index/login` but the notice message doesn't show. I have no idea why.

I have tried commenting out Check 1 but I still have the same problem with Check 2 and Check 3.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.